# $window.location = pdfLocation; not downloading PDF AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, angular-promise, window.location

I am receiving the location of a pdf document in angular, and I cant get it to consistently download.

It works on my home laptop, but not whilst at work.
Code below

```
RenderService.document('document.pdf', spec).then(function(pdfLocation) {
    $window.location = pdfLocation;
});
```

Works in Chrome on Ubuntu at home, not on the same set up at work. Does anyone know any reason why the operation of '$window.location' wouldn't be idempotent?

Update:
Also works on FF on my work machine, just not Chrome

Comment: What "does not work" exactly stay for? Is the link broken? Doesn't it trigger a download?

Comment: Nothing happens, the js parser passes that line and no action is taken

Comment: You have some add blocker or anti vir software running on this machine at work?

Comment: Potentially, although it has worked before, and one day just stopped. I'll look into if anything new was added

Comment: Interestingly it works in Firefox on my machine at work, thanks for the tip

Comment: As specified in this question, you can use an hidden iframe: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: iFrame sounds like overkill, it would be better to generate an <a> tag and trigger the click on that but I'm more here to find a solution to why this doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

This mostly happends if you have some third part software installed or the browser security is configured as to high. Check for addblocker & antivir software on your machine and also check the security configuration in your browser. Ensure that your pdf location is based on `HTTPS` if your application is running on `HTTPS`.

For Chrome & Safari try to set your `window.location.href` property instead of `window.location`. This should work for all browser so.

```
RenderService.document('document.pdf', spec).then(function(pdfLocation) {
    window.location.href = pdfLocation;
    return false;
});
```

Here is a [plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/yQPB4TLzYcIwk8ghPiON?p=preview) which does run well in chrome.

Comment: The $widow.location.href didn't work, but the error does go away when I deselect "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites" from advanced settings. (I don't want to mark this as correct as it will confuse people passing by to the actual issue here)

Comment: Is your `pdfLocation` holding a full qualified URL like `http://domain/download.pdf`? Try is one time with `window` instead of AngularJS instance `$window`. I'll create a fiddle for testing .. can't belive it =)

Comment: $window.location works in your plunker when i change it, and both my site and the pdf are on https. so its neither of those. I also tried window instead of $window and it's not that either. My url is                 "https://somelocalhostproxy:8443/etc/document.pdf", I'm guessing Chrome is blocking it as it knows it's local

Comment: Crazy crazy, it should work for local domains too. Could you add `return false;` as provided in my answer?

Comment: I'm afraid it made no difference

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought =(

Comment: Does it work if you enter a TEST PDF url like `https://www.suec.de/Download/PDF/Test.pdf` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139351/discussion-between-lin-and-ben-taliadoros).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lin I realised the issue was chrome blocking my download due to the advanced security option in Chrome:
"Protect you and your device from dangerous sites"

I'm not sure how to get around it yet, and will update this answer if I find a solution

Comment: Cheers m8 =),  glad to help. Should i post an answer? ;)

Comment: Sure go ahead :)